# If $g(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow y$, then $f(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x\rightarrow y$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $y \in A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in A$. If $g(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow y$, then $f(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow y$.

I need to either prove this or provide a counter-example. My gut says that if y is not a limit point, then this is false. But this material is fairly new and I am not understanding it well. Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: Are you assuming f to be continuous?

Comment: We actually haven't even defined continuous yet!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=[0,\infty)$, $B=\Bbb R$, $g(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\ge0\\ 0&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$, $f=\left.g\right\rvert_A$ and $y=0$.

Comment: But y isn't an element of A here.

Comment: Now it is.${}{}$

Comment: Haha. That's what I figured, but I didn't know if it broke anything.

Comment: Wait, but in this case don't we have lim g(x) undefined and lim f(x) = 1?

Comment: Yes, we do.${}$

Comment: but with how it is worded, I think we want the limit to be defined at g(x)? I believe I have worked out another example, though

Comment: It isn't what has been written up there.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $B=\mathbb R$, $A=\{0\}$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Then as you suspected, $\{0\}$ is a limit point of $B$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0, x \in B} g(x)=0$. However the limit of $f$ at $0$ is not defined as $0$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Comment: $A$ is not a subset of $B$ in this example.

Comment: @Riley You’re right. I switched $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If the downvoter can explain, that will be appreciated.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net In your example, $f$ is a function from one-point subset of $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Every such a function is continuous (the induced topology on the one-point subset is actually the trivial topology) and has a well-defined limit. (It's not me who downvoted)

Comment: (Also not me.) $g$ is a function from $A$, not $B$, and $f$ is a function from $B$, not $A$. Then $g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0 = y \in A$ but $f(x)$ doesn't have to approach $0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, e.g. take $f(0) = 0$ so $f = g$ on $A$ but take, for instance, $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: @dsw Please refer to the definition of a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point?wprov=sfti1). Here the topological space is $\mathbb R$ and $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$. A limit of a function can be defined on a subset $S$ of a topological space at a point $a$. Providing that $a $ is a limit point of $S$. If I understand the exercice, this is the aim of what the student will understand.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  If I understand the exercise correctly, it asks nothing about limit points.

Comment: We are only a couple of chapter into intro real analysis. Limit points were defined right before this exercise, making me assume they're relevant. anything involving topology is going to go way over my head.